# How to convexify log(convex) function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convexity, nonconvex-programming, bounds

I have the following optimization problem: \begin{align}\max_x&\quad\log_2(1+|a+bx|^2+cx^2)\\\text{s.t.}&\quad0\le x\le1\\&\quad(1-x^2)\ge\text{constant}\end{align} where $a$ and $b$ are two complex numbers, and $c$ is a real positive number.

Does anyone have any idea regarding how this objective function can be converted into a convex one?

Is it true to say that the optimal value of $x$ is equal to $\sqrt{1-\text{constant}}$?

Comment: Just pointing out that since you are maximising, maybe you want to get a concave function instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are maximizing a convex quadratic (the monotonic log is irrelevant) so the maximum is attained at the border, i.e. either $0$ or $\min(1,\sqrt{1-\text{constant}})$.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, I have another question!
what if we have the following constraint $log_2(1+|a+b*x|^2+c*x^2)\geq constant2$ as well?
Do we get the previous solution still?

Comment: If you pick the maximum, and it does not satisfy that constraint, then the problem is obviously not solvable.

Comment: So, I cannot derive a close-form solution! Shall I resort to SCA approach?

Comment: I have already given you the closed-form solution, and the added constraint does not change anything as it either will be a redundant constraint (the maximal solution satisfies it) or render the problem infeasible (the maximal solution does not satisfy it)

Comment: I get it, Thank you so much!